# Swig std::map<std::string, T>

Tags: dictionary, swig

I'm trying to convert a C++ std::map to C#.
I know that there is a way to do this using std_map.i but it only seems to work if I write for every class a new template like

```
%template(String_Foo_Map) std::map<std::string, Foo>;
%template(String_Bar_Map) std::map<std::string, Bar>;
...
```

Is there a way to this is automatically, no matter what type is used? Something like

```
%template(String_T_Map) std::map<std::string, T>;
```

and it would create

```
String_Foo_Map
String_Bar_Map
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define macros for SWIG similarly to how it is done for Numpy

Header file

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

class A {
public:
  A() : m_a(1.0f) {}
  float m_a;
};

class B {
public:
  B() : m_b(2.0f) {}
  float m_b;
};
```

SWIG interface file

```
%module test

%{
#include "test.h"
%}

%include "std_map.i"
%include "std_string.i"
%include "test.h"

%define %my_templates(DATA_TYPE)
%template(String_ ## DATA_TYPE ## Map) std::map<std::string, DATA_TYPE>;
%enddef

%my_templates(A)
%my_templates(B)
```

The example is now complete

Comment: You can see examples of how to concatenate string for declaring you templates in Section 7.5 of  http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Preprocessor.html

Comment: Thank you Jens, I think this is the best thing to do in this case. I will mark your answer as solved/most helpful.